# Xdebug is stepping to wrong lines when navigating in NetBeans

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug

Today when launched my xdebug session in NetBeans 8.2 it would not work unless I ticked the stop at first line of file in the options. On top off that it's not stopping at my set breakpoints, and stepping into catch clauses that definitely weren't triggered.

Is this a bug in NetBeans or xdebug and how might I troubleshoot?

Running WAMP on Windows 10
PHP 5.5.12
Xdebug 2.2.5

Comment: Is that a new project or the same one as before? Does it work in other projects? Any symbolic links anywhere in the path?  I suggest to collect xdebug log and see what it will have to say: https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_log P.S. Updating to xdebug 2.4.1 may also help.